# Symfony doctrine empty relation in behat tests

Tags: symfony, doctrine, relation, behat

I have a problem with behat in symfony 2. I have two entities:

//Transaction

DM\MultiStepFormBundle\Entity\Transaction:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: DM\MultiStepFormBundle\Repository\Transaction\TransactionRepository
    table: rb_multistepform_transaction

```
indexes:
    transaction_id_index:
        columns: [ transaction_id ]

id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    created_at:
        type: datetime
        nullable: false
    transaction_id:
        type: string
        length: 128
        nullable: false
    is_client_new:
        type: boolean
        options:
            default: false
    utm_source:
        type: string
        length: 255
        nullable: true
    utm_medium:
        type: string
        length: 255
        nullable: true
    utm_campaign:
        type: string
        length: 255
        nullable: true
    user_agent:
        type: text
        nullable: true
    http_referer:
        type: string
        length: 255
        nullable: true
    ip:
        type: string
        length: 32
        nullable: true
    status:
        type: smallint
        nullable: false
        options:
            default: 0
    continue_service_run:
        type: boolean
        nullable: false
        options:
            default: false           
    continue_serivce_run_datetime:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true

oneToMany:
    items:
        targetEntity: DM\MultiStepFormBundle\Entity\TransactionItem
        mappedBy: transaction
        cascade: [persist, merge, remove]

manyToOne:
    client:
        targetEntity: DM\KlienciBundle\Entity\Client
        inversedBy: multistepform_transactions
        joinColumn:
            name: client_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

//TransactionItem

```
DM\MultiStepFormBundle\Entity\TransactionItem:
type: entity
repositoryClass: DM\MultiStepFormBundle\Repository\Transaction\TransactionRepository
table: rb_multistepform_transaction_item
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }

indexes:
    partner_status_index:
        columns: [ partner_name, status ]

fields:
    type:
        type: smallint
        nullable: false
    partner_name:
        type: string
        length: 128
        nullable: true
    status:
        type: smallint
        nullable: false
        options:
            default: 0
    link_id:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
    product_id:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
    pixelconversion_hash:
        type: string
        length: 128
        nullable: true
    partner_api_response:
        type: json_array
        nullable: true
    clicked:
        type: boolean
        nullable: false
        options:
            default: 0
    clicked_datetime:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
    order_nr:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
    highlighted:
        type: boolean
        nullable: false
        options:
            default: false

manyToOne:
    transaction:
        targetEntity: DM\MultiStepFormBundle\Entity\Transaction
        inversedBy: items
        cascade: [persist, merge, remove]
        joinColumn:
            name: transaction_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

When i testing a service where I have such loops:

$transactions = $this->transactionRepository->getTransactionsByContinueServiceRunInDateRange(0, $minDateTime, $maxDateTime);

```
foreach ($transactions as $transactionKey => $singleTransaction) {
    //in this place, relationships are not taken 
    $transactionItems = $singleTransaction->getItems();       
    //when it performs a test query items are downloaded correctly
    $transactionItemsQuery = $this->transactionRepository->getItems($singleTransaction->getId());
}
```

In which i needs to get items from the reverse relation. With a normal call to the site in symfony, the relationships are correct and everything is ok. 
In the case of activating test in behat, relations in the variable $transactionItems are an empty collection. The data surely exists in the database because in the variable $transactionItemsQuery as I get data from query I have correct data.

Has anyone ever encountered something like that in behat?

Comment: Are you sure Behat is accessing the same DB? Usually Behat accesses a test db. Check if you have any `config_dev.yml` file with a different db connection/name data

Comment: I have another database for testing and in the $transactions variable I have data that I added in the test.